# Counting how many times unique values occur in an array across a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I have a collection of users. The user document is a very simple document, and looks like this:

```
{
   username: "player101",
   badges: ["score10", "score100"]
}
```

So how can I query to see how many times each unique value in the badges array occurs across the entire collection?

Answer (score 1):

Use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages, where you can sum badges with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) arithmetic operator

```
db.players.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $unwind: "$badges" 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: 
      { 
        _id: "$badges", 
        count: { $sum: 1 } 
      } 
  } 
]);
```

on collection `players` with documents

```
{ "username" : "player101", "badges" : [ "score10", "score100" ] }
{ "username" : "player102", "badges" : [ "score11", "score100" ] }
{ "username" : "player103", "badges" : [ "score11", "score101" ] }
{ "username" : "player104", "badges" : [ "score12", "score100" ] }
```

gives you the result

```
{ "_id" : "score101", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "score11", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "score12", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "score100", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "score10", "count" : 1 }
```